# Can CPython speak with WCF?

Tags: .net, python, wcf, nettcpbinding, cpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276184/wcf-and-python)

I would like to write a CPython app that would consume WCF services that use `NetNamedPipeBinding` and `NetTcpBinding`. It is possible? What library enables that?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276184/wcf-and-python